# Hibernate Envers How to record additional audit data such as table name being audited

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, hibernate-envers

I have implemented a solution of Hibernate **Envers**.

I am extending RevisionLister by creating my own class to store the system username:

```
    import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionListener;

    public class CustomRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

        public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
            CustomRevisionEntity revision = (CustomRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
            revision.setUsername(System.getProperty("user.name")); // for testing

        }

    }
```

This does the job, but what I want to do, is to make a more comprehensive record, that would include the table name being audited.

Does anyone know how I could do this. I cannot find any documentation relating to recording the table name?

Answer (score 3):

See [example 15.2 in the envers doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-tracking-modified-entities-revchanges) how to get the modified entity class(es). Then slightly change the code to obtain the table name from the entity class (assumes you use JPA/Hibernate annotations on entity classes):

```
public class CustomEntityTrackingRevisionListener
             implements EntityTrackingRevisionListener {
    @Override
    public void entityChanged(Class entityClass, String entityName,
                              Serializable entityId, RevisionType revisionType,
                              Object revisionEntity) {
        // either javax.persistence.Table or org.hibernate.annotations.Table
        Table tableAnnotation = entityClass.getAnnotation(Table.class);
        if (tableAnnotation != null)
          String tableName = tableAnnotation.getName();
          ((CustomTrackingRevisionEntity)revisionEntity).addTable(tableName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Envers can track the table name of the records being audited out of the box , but I know it can track the **entity name** instead which can be enabled by [three different ways](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-tracking-modified-entities-revchanges)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `DefaultTrackingModifiedEntitiesRevisionEntity`, or  configure org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision parameter to true.

See Envers Doc: [Tracking entity names modified during revisions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-tracking-modified-entities-revchanges)